# React Native javascript object value to array

Tags: javascript, listview, reactjs, charts, native

**What I am trying to accomplish.**

Hydrate chart data with my data from firebase

**Issue**

The chart I am using want's data in this format

```
data: [
    { value: 15 },
    { value: 10 },
    { value: 12 },
    { value: 11 },
  ]
```

I have the this.datasource that populates my listview and then I can get the values I want in the chart, just the wrong format. I don't know how to get the data without the quotes.

> var chartArrayFilter = (JSON.stringify(items, ['value']));

console.log =  [{"value":"5"},{"value":"9"},{"value":"0"},{"value":"4"}]

**My Question**

I have tried to hack that array (or string) and remove the double quotes, but I don't thing React Native lets that happen. Am I doing this completely wrong? How do I get the data I want in that format from a javascript object?

This is the package I am working with
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-charts

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### If you don't need to stringify:

It looks to me like you're using `JSON.stringify` as a way to remove unnecessary properties from an array of objects. For example, **assuming your `items` array looks something like this**:

```
items = [
  {
    value: 5,
    foo: 'bar'
  },
  {
    value: 9,
    bar: 'baz'
  }
];
```

then calling `JSON.stringify` on that will give you `"[{"value":5},{"value":9}]"` (notice how everything is, well, stringified).

Perhaps a better approach would be the following:

```
var chartArrayFilter = items.map(function(item) {
  return {value: item.value};
});
```

which will give you `[{value: 5}, {value: 6}]`. Notice nothing is stringified in that structure; it's just an array of objects.

### If you DO need to stringify:

If, for whatever reason, you *do* need to call `JSON.stringify` on your `items` array to pick the properties you want, you can simply reverse it with

`JSON.parse(items)`

**after** you call `JSON.stringify`. This will give you `[{value: 5}, {value: 6}, ...]`, same as above.

### Conclusion

Once you've prepared your `items` array in one of the two ways mentioned above, you should be able to painlessly pass it into `react-native-charts`!

Comment: You rock! The item.map bit was exactly what I needed. I found out that I did not need to stringify it after all. I love how you formatted your answer too!

Comment: Glad I could help! Best wishes! :)